# Area of Convergence for $\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z}{(1+z^2)^n}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, complex-analysis

I want to show that the series
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z}{(1+z^2)^n}$$
converges for all values of $z\in \mathbb{C}$ outside the region $|1+z^2|=1$.

I've tried using ratio test, but I get the condition that the series will convergence only when $|1+z^2|>1$. I'm not sure if this is all the points outside there region $|1+z^2|=1$ and the calculation quickly gets messy. Any slick ways of solving this?

Comment: What you get is a leminiscate, whose unbounded component is of the form $|z^2+1| > 1.$ I presume that is what the question intends, so you are done.

Comment: How, do you see it's a leminscate and how does the unbounded component prove the series converges? What about the region where $|z^2+1|<1$?

Comment: I presume "outside the region" refers to the exterior of the leminiscate; $|z^2+1| < 1$ is the interior. If you outline your calculations I can check them. It might mean it converges everywhere but on the boundary of the leminiscate, but I haven't checked convergence inside. Convergence outside is trivial since the denominator will grow rapidly.

Comment: If you want to check it's a leminiscate, write $z= x+iy$ and rearrange using the pythagorean theorem